# Как вывод в консоль дожидается выполнения async функции?

Tags: javascript, ajax, async-await

Всем привет. Есть следующий код:

```
async function func() {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  return await response.json();
}
console.log(func()); // успешный промис, результат которого - массив пользователей
```

Что выполняется внутри func?

1. `fetch` возвращает промис.
2. Промис делает get запрос.
3. Получает ответ - объект `Response`.
4. Потом резолвится этим объектом.
5. Тем временем, `await`, перед `fetch`, ждёт выполнения всех 4 пунктов, чтобы получить результат промиса и отдать этот результат в `const response`.
6. Затем мы переводим результат из json-строки в массив - это тоже происходит не сразу, а с определённой задержкой.
7. Поэтому мы добавляем еще один `await`, чтобы дождаться и этой операции.
8. И вот только после того, когда все вышестоящие пункты выполнились, вот тогда и происходит return из func.

Но! Вывод в консоль - это синхронный код, а значит не ждёт выполнения всех пунктов (асинхронных операций). По сути для вывода в консоль тело func должно быть таким:

```
async function func() {
  const response = undefined; // undefined, потому что синхронный код не ждёт, когда придет ответ от сервера, он тупо идет дальше...
  return undefined; // тут тоже возвращается undefined, потому что вывод не ждёт выполнения - await response.json()
}
console.log(func()); успешный промис с результатом undefined
```

И вот сам вопрос - почему выводится промис, результат которого массив? Почему не выводится промис с результатом undefined? То есть получается вывод в консоль успевает дождаться всех операций у `func`, верно?

Ремарка: я знаю, что `async` возвращает промис и резолвит его со значением, которое идёт после `return` (если после `return` идет промис, то возвращается он). А если у функции нет конкретного возвращаемого значения или вообще, её тело пустое, то вернётся успешный промис с результатом `undefined`.

Comment: абсолютно то же самое что в предыдущем вопросе. На самом деле выводит Promise вообще без значения, в состоянии `Pending` просто когда ты раскрываешь его чтобы увидеть детали - Promise уже разрешился и получил значение.

Comment: @Grundy Смотри, если выводится промис в `Pending`, значит вывод в консоль знает, что из ф-ии возвращается промис, который когда-то должен зарезолвиться. Но до этого, у нас еще было обращение к серверу, получение от него ответа и так далее. Как консоль успел дождаться этих операций? Он же их не ждёт, а соответственно нам должен вернуться промис с `fulfilled` и значением undefined, попробуй сам запустить второй вариант кода.

Comment: консоль ничего не ждет. Promise возвращается сразу, как доходит до `await`, именно в этот момент происходит вывод в консоль.

Comment: @Grundy А вообще, правильно то, что если мы из async функции явно возвращаем промис, то тогда из функции вернётся этот самый явный промис, а не тот, который async функция возвращает неявно?

Comment: не понял вопрос.